# Where can I find full wing polar data to validate an aerodynamic code?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

I am looking for polar data of a full wing to validate an aerodynamics code I an working on.
I am looking for the Cl, Cd polars (and Cmy) and the planform and airfoil geometry, I am also looking for the polars computed at various Mach numbers.
I looks through the Internet and read many AIAA papers but I never found all the elements I am looking for in one of them.
I heard about the ONERA M6, DLR-F4 and DPW reference wings but I never found a full study of one of those (with numerical data). If someone can provide me with such data I would be very happy.

To go one step further I am also looking for such kind of data for a straight wing.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Can you clarify what you mean by polar data? Do you simply mean you wish to find the Cl, Cd & Cmy for a known wing geometry?

Comment: What I mean by polar data are the curves of Cl as a function of AoA and the curves of Cd and Cmy as a function of AoA or Cl for a given geometry and for given Mach and Reynolds numbers. I mean data because in many articles they provide with some curves but I would prefer having .dat or .txt files.

Answer (score 1):

"Theory of Wing Sections" by Ira H Abbott and A. Von Doenhoff has extensive graphed and tabulated data for Cl and Cd vs alpha of a wide variety of wing sections.

Airfoiltools.com has also got a lot of the data you're looking for, but from a quick scan it doesnt appear to cite their sources. The data is readily available in tabulated format, however.

In either case, its not explicitly mentioned but I'd assume that the data provided is for wings of straight planform. I'd guess that you can find some kind of formula to account for the difference either in the Abbott book mentioned or elsewhere, possibly applying a variation of the blade element method.

Comment: Actually I am not looking for wing section polars but for full wing polars.

Comment: I need to have CFD data computed with a 3D solver as I want to validate my own 2D to 3D corrections